# Query to get the percentage of orders placed by a customer

Tags: sql

I have a `Product` table that has a column `OrderStatusID`.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product where CustomerID = 10;
```

The problem: **find the percentage of `Products` where `OrderStatusID` is not null.**

Comment: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-percent-to-total.html that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(OrderStatus) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(*)*100 Percentage
FROM dbo.Product
WHERE CustomerID = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is like this

```
SELECT 100*Count(OrderStatusID)/(SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.Product) FROM dbo.Product;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @total numeric(10,2)
select @total =count(*) from orders

select customerID, cast(100*count(*)/@total as numeric(10,2)) as Percentage
from orders
where customerID=10
group by customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(CustomerID)
    as Percentage
FROM dbo.Product
```